# Filter items with groups per user

Tags: filter

I have a list of items where a field is a group of users.
Is it possible to filter the list to that the person viewing the page will only see the items where he is a member of the users listed in the item ?

Example:

```
 - Item 1
   -- Title = A
   -- Members = X, Y, Z

 - Item 2
   -- Title = B
   -- Members = U, V, Y
```

So that user X would only see item 1, user V would only see item 2, and user Y would see both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, we solved this issue by writing a piece of code that dynamically set the permissions to the item. Using my above example, users X, Y, Z have contribute rights on A.

Answer (score 3):

I solved same problem by dynamicaly setting permissions on list items in event receiver. But this solution is not scalable at all.

I will recomend create Folders with unique security assignments and view for all items without folders.

Comment: This is one of the few effective uses of Folders there is in SharePoint.

Comment: I cannot use folders as this is about a custom list of items with various fields, including a team field containing several users.

Answer (score 0):

In some cases u can use XsltListViewWebPart and create SPView 'on the fly' - clone exist view, add/remove fields, setup SPQuery and set this SPView to your XsltListViewWebPart instance.

This solution also have a lot of limits but sometimes it is useful trick.

Comment: There is no way to filter items in query by user group membership, unfortunately.

Comment: Actually, it is - Membership Element (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa544234.aspx), isn't it?